# Marching Through Republic of Georgia

Tags: story-identification

I thought it was a novel by Philip K Dick but there's no mention of it in his novels.

The novel is similar to the Dorsai theme of Gordon R Dickson, and is set in the Republic of Georgia with one army marching through a pass facing another army.

I'll look into S.M. Stirling's novel to a greater degree, but a cursory look gave me the notion that this wasn't the author I was looking for.

Comment: What about this book makes it science fiction?

Comment: S M Stirling's _Marching Through Georgia_ is indeed set in the country rather than the US state, with two armies facing off against each other. It's probably the one that you want.

Comment: @Richard - assuming *Marching Through Georgia* is correct, it's an alternate history in which the Nazis face off against another totalitarian state with origins in South Africa, "The Domination of Draka" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Domination )

Comment: @hypnosifl -  Are "alternate history" books on topic? I presume yes.

Comment: @Richard - Yes, it looks like they're covered even if there aren't other science fictional elements like time travel involved: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35/are-questions-about-alternate-history-on-or-off-topic

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I thought so; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37/what-is-and-what-isnt-considered-science-fiction

Comment: NOT!! And yes to alternate history. This book didn't have Nazis, and as best I can recall there was an element of Dickson' with an army leader showing 'heightened' faculties.

Comment: @user30252 - can you remember approximately what era it was set? What was the level of technology/weaponry? And do you remember anything about the cultures of the two sides in this war? BTW there's a big archive of summaries of alternate history stories at http://www.uchronia.net/ and it's searchable, here are some stories whose summaries have "Georgia" in them: http://www.uchronia.net/bib.cgi/search.html?id=georgia

Answer (score 7):

S.M. Stirling is your guy.

[image]

> The story details how Eric's single infantry company takes and holds a
>   small village strategically located on the crucial Ossetian Military
>   Highway over the Caucasus Mountains.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Jeez, I thought for sure Stirling would be correct.

So, how about Harry Turtledove's Marching Through Peachtree?

[image]

It's a retelling of Sherman's campaign, but with all the specifics (North, South, slaves are blonde,etc) reversed. It does use magic.

Comment: Surely that would be set in the US state of Georgia, and not in the Republic of Georgia as specified in the question.

Comment: Well, no. It's set in the fictitious kingdom of Detina, where the North tries to break away from the rule of the South so as to maintain its' peculiar institution of serfdom - with blonde, blue-eyed serfs being the subject of contention - but it's clearly the Civil War Georgia campaign. I thought the change in country names might account for a memory confusion on the part of the OP.